# Saving the values returned from as.POSIXct or as.POSIXlt into a column

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm simply trying to save these dates (that I originally inputted as strings from a .csv file extracted from an SQL database) in date/time format so that I can calculate differences between the dates. More specifically, I'm given three dates in UCT: two of them are date/time fields that serve as a time range and one of them is a delivery time (as date/time). I simply have to check to see if the delivery time was within a given time window.

Trying to convert strings to date/time and save them in a column...

So after trying: (with as.POSIXct and as.POSIXlt)

```
test[,"requested_delivery_start_date"] <-
as.POSIXct(test[,"requested_delivery_start_date"], tz = "GMT", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

and getting erroneous results,

I tried:

```
for(i in c(1:nrow(input_subset))){
    test[i,"requested_delivery_start_date"] <- 
    as.POSIXct(test[i,"requested_delivery_start_date"], tz = "GMT", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
}
```

and I got the following errors: (there were many errors of the same type, I just pasted the first three)

```
warnings() Warning messages:
1: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, iseq, value = structure(1528822800, class = c("POSIXct", ... : invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, iseq, value = structure(1528768800, class = c("POSIXct", ... : invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, iseq, value = structure(1528768800, class = c("POSIXct", ... : invalid factor level, NA generated
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I stored them into new column values and simply have to add them to a data frame after I convert the timezone to local time zones.

i.e.

```
newStart <- as.POSIXct(input_subset[,"requested_delivery_start_date"], tz = "GMT", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

Then I can convert the dates in newStart and append them to a data frame.